Canon CCApi - The event polling API consistently returns a 404 error
I'm attempting to use Canon's CCAPI to download the most recent image captured. The documentation recommends using the event polling API to retrieve the image's file path immediately after a photo is taken, but I'm encountering an issue.  When I try to access the event polling API (/ccapi/ver100/event/polling), I consistently receive an HTTP 404 error (page not found). Have you encountered this problem before? If so, could you please share how you resolved it? Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.
I'm using a Canon EOS R50 camera, with firmware version 1.2.0 and CCAPI version 1.3.0.
I am expecting to receive an HTTP response code of 200 and a response body containing events.
